# What is the difference between "temporada" and "estación"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

The words `temporada` and `estación` both mean `season` in English. Is there any difference between these two words? How can I use them properly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use "estación" when you refer to one of the four seasons of the year: summer, fall/autumn, winter or spring.

The word "temporada" will be used to refer to some period during which an activity is performed or some business is conducted, as in *temporada de esquí*. The "temporada" may coincide with a certain season, and then we have *temporada invernal, temporada de verano*, but these will always be used when there is some implicit activity that takes place during the period in question: *En la temporada de verano los hoteles trabajan a pleno* (In this case, "temporada de verano" is used to describe the hotel business during the summer.)

Comment: Agregaría que son sinónimos en expresiones como *ropa/fruta de temporada/estación*.

Answer (score 3):

**Estación** means "season" or "station", depending on context.
**Estación de verano** ("season of summer", literally, or "summer season").

**Temporada** means "time" (over a week, a period of Time), as in "Temporada de verano" (summertime).

Comment: There is already an answer which says this and with more detail. When you have more reputation you will be able to up-vote an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer is great but I want to give you a couple other ways of thinking about this.  *Estación* is at the foundation, at the level of the equinox.  It's based on what happens astronomically with the earth and the sun.  *Temporada* means *in the time of*, for example: *In summertime*, when the cicadas sing, you get in the mood for lemonade.

The other idea I want to share is that when you take a train, you stop at stations.  Also, as you go cycling along through the seasons of the year, you also stop at stations.  December 21st -- your train stops at the Beginning of Winter Station.  Etc.

Hopefully these ways of associating the cognates and their meanings will help you remember the difference.

Comment: @walen - Oh, you went even farther.  Very good.  I was just associating *estación* with the train stations on the Earth's annual voyage around the sun.  For *temporal* I forgot to point out the connection between *temporada* and *tiempo*.